# How to add more than 1 theme parameter to Material App Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, themes

I have a normal `MaterialApp` Widget in my `flutter` app. And I want to add more than 1 `theme` parameter to it...

Like so:-

```
   theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: kGetAppFont(context, languageCode)),
   theme: ThemeProvider.themeOf(themeContext).data,
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user can change the app theme, you can store selected theme in Settings (you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin). In app you should set in by read value from Settings and detect theme class by its value:

`Main` class fragment:

```dart
theme: _prefs.currentTheme();
```

`Prefs` class fragment:

```dart
ThemeData currentTheme() {
  return _instance.getString('theme') == 'dark' ? AppTheme.dark : AppTheme.light;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in any shape or form

Comment: Why do you trying to add multiple themes in an app? Can you add use cases to the question?